# Problems deploying Wagtail 6

Tags: python, django, wagtail, wagtail-admin

I'm upgrading from Wagtail 4.2.4 to 6.0.1 and I made a lot of changes taking into consideration all the deprecated libraries. Everything works localy but when I try to deploy to my development site the GitHub Action runner fails with the following Error:

`remote: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'wagtail.contrib.modeladmin'         remote: !    Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.`

I checked and the wagtail-robots library still uses the deprecated contrib.modeladmin.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Until wagtail-robots updates, you can install modeladmin from https://github.com/wagtail-nest/wagtail-modeladmin. But you may need to update the import paths.